# Números não estão somando corretamente

Tags: php, mongodb

Estou fazendo uma busca no `MongoDB` e trazendo a soma de alguns valores. Ele traz corretamente os valores que estão lá, somando eles. O problema está sendo quando eu preciso por exemplo, pegar o valor 1 e somar com o valor 2. Tenho como exemplo 2 números:

```
Valor 1: 980
Valor 2: 2.094
```

E a soma desse resultado está dando **982.094** sendo que deria ser **3.074**.

O código que uso:

```
$queryReceitaMeta = $this->mongo_db->aggregate('metas_receita', $aggregate);

  if(count($queryReceitaMeta['result']) > 0){

    $rowQueryReceitaMeta = $queryReceitaMeta['result'][0];

    foreach($meses as $mes){

      $totalReceitaMeta += $rowQueryReceitaMeta['soma_'.$mes];
    }
  }
```

Nesse código ele soma o resultado do ano inteiro, sendo que ele soma cada mês (Janeiro-Dezembro).

> Quando tiro o "." (ponto) dos valores, então ele soma certo. Usando a
>   função `str_replace` ele funciona normalmente.

Comment: O `.` nos EUA e alguns outros países simboliza o começo das casas decimais, assim como a `,` no Brasil. Me parece que o comportamento é correto. Sugiro você conferir as opções de localidade (locale) do seu banco e do PHP pra ver se estão alinhadas.

Comment: Fiquei maior tempão pensando em como deveria ser 3.074... A soma que quer fazer deveria de ser `0.980 + 2.094`, isso daria 3.074. Se você deseja 3.074 (três mil e setenta e quatro) você deveria omitir o `.`, dessa forma `980+2094`. Somar `980.000 + 3.074` vai dar `982.094`, *que é o que está fazendo*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porquê, por padrão, o PHP considera o caractere `.` como separador da parte decimal, que é o padrão nos EUA, por exemplo.

Nós escrevemos 1.234,00 para representar o número mil duzentos e trinta e quatro, já eles escrevem 1,234.00. Então o número 2.094, ao invés de ser considerado dois mil, é dois e noventa e quatro centésimos.

Basta verificar fazendo:

```
$a = 2.094;
$b = 3;

if ($a > $b) {
  echo "$a é maior que $b";
} else {
  echo "$a é menor que $b";
}
```

O resultado será:

```
2.094 é menor que 3
```

Então, para contornar isso você realmente precisa remover o `.` do valor, visto que o PHP não possui um caractere que divide as casas dos milhares. Para representar o valor 2.094 você precisa ter `$value = 2094`.

Se ao final, você deseja exibir o valor com as devidas separações, pode utilizar a função [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php):

```
$a = 2.094;
$b = 980;

$a = str_replace(".", "" , $a);
$b = str_replace(".", "" , $b);

$c = $a + $b;

echo number_format($c, 2, ',', '.');
```

A saída é:

```
3.074,00
```